# How to stop and restart `QApplication` in `unittest` framework?

Tags: python, qt, unit-testing, pyqt

I am a `Qt` newbie and I'm developing a user interface library based on `Qt`. I'd like to start the main `QApplication` on `setUp` and close it on `tearDown` so I don't have any events or other issues leaking between tests. Here's my `setUp`/`tearDown` methods now:

```
class _QtTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        """Set up a QAppplication on each test case."""
        try:
            QApplication = QtGui.QApplication
        except AttributeError:
            QApplication = QtWidgets.QApplication

        self.qt_app = QApplication.instance()
        if self.qt_app is None:
            self.qt_app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    def tearDown(self):
        """Clear the QApplication's event queue."""
        # After each test, empty the event queue.
        # This should help to make sure that there aren't any event-based race
        # conditions where a C/C++ object is deleted before a slot is called.
        self.qt_app.sendPostedEvents()
        self.qt_app.quit()
```

Unfortunately that last `self.qt_app.quit()` seems to shut down the `QApplication` permanently on all successive tests. Is there a way I can restart a new `QApplication` in the `setUp` method?

Comment: Have you considered using something like [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) with the [pytest-qt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-qt) plugin? I haven't used either of these myself, but they both appear to be mature, well-maintained projects, with reasonably good [documentation](https://pytest-qt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `::exec()` and `::exit()` methods of `QApplication` for your requirement.

Calling `::exec()` enters the main event loop. Call it in your `setUp`.

Calling `::exit()` leaves the main event loop. Call it in your `tearDown`.

Comment: How does this help, given that `quit()` is identical to `exit(0)`?

Comment: True..... My intention is he can use "exec" to start the application. Rest is for readability.

Comment: Hi, I tried this, I think the `pyqt` equivalent is `exec_` but that is a blocking call. Putting it in `setUp` causes the whole lot to freeze. I'm not sure what to do here. Would it make sense to launch it in a thread?

Comment: Indeed. `exec` is a built-in function in Python, so the PyQt function is named `exec_`. And yes, the `exec` call is blocking until the event loop is stopped (by `exit`), so you need to start it from another thread.